# Regex split phrase to words, but ignore spaces within tags

Tags: regex

I need to split phrase to words, but ignore text within defined tag
For example

Input

```
<i>111 111 111</i> 222 333 444 <i>555 666</i> 888 999 <i>000 111</i>
```

Output

```
<i>111 111 111</i>
222
333
444
<i>555 666</i>
888
999
<i>000 111</i>
```

Comment: what do you mean be "defined tag" - any tag?

Comment: Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead. Look for text nodes which have no child nodes and split the contents.

Comment: What language are you using? Are all your examples that simple (i.e. no nested tags, no xml comments, no CDATA blocks)

Comment: I use .NET and if somebody give me example with Regex.Split it will really usefull

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/<i>[\d\s]*<\/i>|\d+/g
```

Explanation:

- For strings within `<i>` tags, both whitespace and numerals will be included in the match.
- Strings not within the tags cannot include whitespace, so they'll be restricted to numeric strings.
- The `|` alternator is short-circuiting, so it makes sure `<i>111 222 333</i>` will be treated as a single unit, *not* split off into `111`, `222`, and `333`.

Tested on Regexr here, works correctly: http://regexr.com?2uf6j

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting on a space only if the next `<`  that follows is not followed by a slash?

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "<i>111 111 111</i> 222 333 444 <i>555 666</i> 888 999 <i>000 111</i>"
>>> split = re.compile(" (?![^<]*</)")
>>> split.split(test)
['<i>111 111 111</i>', '222', '333', '444', '<i>555 666</i>', '888', '999', '<i>000 111</i>']
```

This will fail if tags can be nested, though (which is a reason why regex is not a good fit for this kind of problem).